# How to check current wallpaper is default or not?

Tags: android, wallpaper

how i'll come to now wheather the current wallpaper is the default one or not.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Sujit, it would be difficult to define what is meant by the default wallpaper.  Take a look at [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) which provides access to the system wallpaper. The documentation states:

> With WallpaperManager, you can get the current wallpaper, get the
>   desired dimensions for the wallpaper, set the wallpaper, and more.